# With Google Website Optimizer's multivariate testing, can I vary multiple css classes on a single div?

Tags: javascript, google-website-optimizer

I would like to use Google Website Optimizer (GWO)'s multivariate tests to test some different versions of a web page.  I can change from version to version just by varying some class tags on a div, i.e. the different versions are of this form:

```
<div id="testing" class="foo1 bar1">content</div>
<div id="testing" class="foo1 bar2">content</div>
<div id="testing" class="foo2 bar1">content</div>
<div id="testing" class="foo2 bar2">content</div>
```

In the ideal, I would be able to use GWO section code in place of each class, and google would just swap in the appropriate tags (`foo1` or `foo2`, `bar1` or `bar2`).  However, naively doing this results in horribly malformed code because I would be trying to put `<script>` tags inside the div's class attribute:

```
<div id="testing" class="
  <script>utmx_section("foo-class")</script>foo1</noscript>
  <script>utmx_section("bar-class")</script>bar1</noscript>
">
  content
</div>
```

And indeed, the browser chokes all over it.

My current best approach is just to use a different div for each variable in the test, as follows:

```
<script>utmx_section("foo-class-div")</script>
  <div class="foo1">
</noscript>
  <script>utmx_section("bar-class-div")</script>
    <div class="bar1">
  </noscript>
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

So testing multiple variables requires layer of div-nesting per variable, and it all seems rather awkward.

Is there a better approach that I could use in which I just vary the classes on a single div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the best way is:

```
<div id="testing">content</div>

<script>
var testingDiv = document.getElementById('testing');
</script>

<script>utmx_section("foo-class-div")</script>
  <script>
  testingDiv.setAttribute('class', testingDiv.getAttribute('class') + ' foo1');
  </script>
</noscript>
<script>utmx_section("bar-class-div")</script>
  <script>
  testingDiv.setAttribute('class', testingDiv.getAttribute('class') + ' bar1');
  </script>
</noscript>
```

Comment: That's definitely an improvement!  (I'll wait a bit to accept the answer to see if anyone else has other approaches.)

Comment: Mind tagging this Q w/ 'javascript' if you can?